# Cannot clear Backbone model array attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im trying to clear data from a Backbone model. Check out the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zcbcjsgw/2/). Th JS is:

```
    $(function(){
    //Define Model
    var loginData = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                token: null,
                data: []
            },

            initialize: function () {
            },

            /*
            * Push name/value to data array. If name is already present, overwrite value. Otherwise, push to end of data array
            */
            addToData: function (nameValue) {
                var data = this.get('data');

                var item, exists = false, index;
                for (var key in data) {
                    // The key is key
                    item = data[key];
                    if (item['name'] === nameValue.name) {
                        exists = true;
                        index = key;
                    }
                }
                if (exists) {
                    //overwrite value if name already in array
                    data[index].value = nameValue.value;
                } else {
                    //add to end of array if name not in array
                    data.push(nameValue);
                }
            },

            clearSensitiveData: function () {
                console.log('in clearSensitiveData');
                this.set('data', [], { silent: true });
                this.set('token', null, { silent: true });

            },
        });


    //Model View & event action
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            this.model = new loginData();
        },
        addData: function(nameValue) {
            this.model.addToData(nameValue);
        },
        clear: function() {
            this.model.destroy();
        }

    });

    var view = new View;

    view.addData({'username':'abcd'});
    console.log('username of view is ');
    console.log(view.model.get('data')[0].username);

    view.model.clearSensitiveData();

    var view2 = new View;

    console.log('username of view2 is (this should fail because model should be cleared) ');
    console.log(view2.model.get('data')[0].username);



}());
```

If you look at the console.log outputs, you see:

```
username of view is  (index):100
abcd (index):101
in clearSensitiveData (index):74
username of view2 is (this should fail because model should be cleared)  (index):107
abcd
```

This is very odd as clearSensitiveData() should reset the "data" array attribute, but somehow, the model remains populated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using

```
defaults: {
  data: []
}
```

You're giving every instance of `loginData` access to the *same* instance of the `data` array. You can't use objects as defaults in a model's `defaults:`, or that same object is referenced by every instance of the model.

From the Backbone docs:

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances. Instead, define defaults as a function.

Either define `defaults` as a function, or manually initialize it in `initialize`:

```
defaults: {
  data: null
},

initialize: function () {
  this.set('data', []);
}
```

As for why your `clearSensitiveData` isn't working, remember, all instances of your model share the same `data` after they're instantiated. You're not *clearing* that shared array, you're just overwriting it in your first instance with a new `[]`. The other model in `view2` still points to the original `data` array, which has not been modified in any way by `clearSensitiveData`.

Your `clearSensitiveData` function is fine, you just need to make sure each instance of your model has its own data array.